# Azure vpn with in bound traffic filtering

Tags: azure, vpn

I am setting up a vm in a virtual network and I am configuring a VPN (site-to-site) to enable connections to our on premise environment.

I am not really a network specialist, so I was wondering what would be the way to secure my virtual network in Azure, so that inbound connections from the VPN are only allowed to the VM and not to any other resources within that virtual networK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to use [Network Security Groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-networks-nsg) for that. They are basically a firewall inside Azure Virtual Networks.

Just create an NSG and create rule to allow traffic to that VM (by default traffic is blocked) from your on-premises.